# Notification Bar in android

Tags: android

I am making an application that uses notification in it but when the notification is about to appear this message is appearing continuously till i turn of the AVD "Unfortunately , System UI has stopped"

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), WorkshopActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, viewIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.web)
                        .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setContentText("Scheduled")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setTicker("Compass");
                NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Please check your LogCat and provide the Stack Trace

Comment: no thing in the logcat

Answer (score 0):

can you please replace getBaseContext() with 'this' or at least getApplicationContext() because BaseContent has a very rare & spesific usage.

and

```
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setTicker("Compass");
```

after this can you build the notificationBuilder,

```
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setTicker("Compass").build();
```

maybe it needs to build before adding style and addign it to manager.

lastly,

```
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder);
```

Comment: getApplicationContext changed nothing and it gives me an error when i build after setticker or i remove the build function from notify parameter :/